# Why the same random state after 'load()' function

Tags: r, random

After loading my `.RData` file from the disc into R, I noticed that the random generator gives the same numbers every time after loading the workspace.

Here is what I mean

```
load(".../file.RData")
sample(10)
#[1]  9  6  1  7  5  2  8  4 10  3

load(".../file.RData")
sample(10)
#[1]  9  6  1  7  5  2  8  4 10  3
```

Do you have any idea why this is the case? I don't remember which function did I use to save the workspace but I have the feeling that its the matter of using `save()` or `save.image()`.

Does `save.image()` save the random state too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does save.image() save the random state too?

Yes, by saving the hidden object `.Random.seed`; see [this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-February/435930.html) on the R-help mailing list.

EDIT:

As suggested by [Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor), I'm adding the recommendation in that mailing list discussion to use `save(list = ls())` instead of `save.image()`; it saves all the non-hidden objects in your global environment, which is usually what you'd want to do from `save.image()` anyway.

Comment: @Gregor Good idea; I've updated the answer to include that suggestion.

Comment: No need to credit me - including relevant info from links in the actual answer is just usual good practice on SO.

Answer (score 0):

`set.seed(NULL)` does re-initialize the random number generator. So,

```
load(".../file.RData")
set.seed(NULL)
```

can address the issue.

---

As for the difference between `save` and `save.image()`, `?save` states that

> `save.image()` is just a short-cut for ‘save my current workspace’, i.e.,
>
> `save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = ".RData", envir = .GlobalEnv)`